# Right way to extend django-registration RegisterForm class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

So i have django regustration, amd i would like to extend the valdation for forms to disallow registrations where the email is already in use - what is the way to do this?

I have this (well, i dont really. My laptop has been commandeered to watch The Voice on hulu by my gf, so this from memory and on my ipad):

```
import django-registration.registrationForm

class customRegistrationForm(form.RegistrationForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        #check here like the one for username!
```

Can i just do that? Also, where should i stick this custom form? I assume i dont't put it with the django-registration folder, so in my apps folder... Am i "meant" to put it in a particular folder? Does it matter if i just stick it in the base app_name folder and call is customRegistrationForm?

Cheers!
Andrew

UPDATE

ok, so I've worked out that to "overwrite" things in django, i need to put the classes in the **init**.py, and that if i want to have a subfolder picked up, it needs its own **init**.py file

The "folder" **init**.py files can be empty

No idea why this is, presumably a python thing? Also, unsure if I can have customRegisterForm.py in a seperate file in the folder, or if it *needs* to be in the **init**.py

anyway, next up is that the override doesn't seem to work how i'd assume.

In Java, when I extend a class, any and all of that classes non-private members are accessible, and behave exactly as they were defined in the parent class. 
In django, i am getting a lot of

> 'customRegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'get_form_class'

or name of the method i didn't explicitly create... am i missing something in the overwrite?

UPDATED UPDATE

i copied the second example from

> http://pbjots.blogspot.com/2012/01/customising-django-registration-no.html

which has worked a treat. Still unsure why the extending doesn't keep all these methods, or if i just *broke* something by blindly copying the code - any ideas?

Comment: You should do a Python tutorial. All of this is standard Python stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the registration form to include emails, you have first extend the **UserCreationForm** to include the email field.  You can create a file called forms.py to include all of yours forms needed for that particular app, but from my experience, you don't often have to use the **init.py**.

Here is an example of how you would extend the registration form to include email:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-Mail")    

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        try:
        User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email

        raise forms.ValidationError("A user with that email address already exists.")
```

Check out this Django tutorial, it outlines the process nicely.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at *RegistrationFormUniqueEmail* form. Its a built-in class from django-registration wich does the work

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
```